# JIRA: How can I see all stories which are closed after x days the sprint has been started?

Tags: jira, scrum, jql, sprint

I'd like to see two things. - For me only it's interesting to see the effective working time on a story to identify some team optimization mechanics.

First I need one filter in Jira that shows all tasks which are planned in a sprint and get closed after more than 5 workingdays (Monday to Friday) - there's no sense to filter out if closed in or out of the sprint.

The second I'd like to see all tasks which are planned in a sprint and get closed after less than 5 workingdays (Monday to Friday).

<--
Actually I use something of this:

### (sprint in (xx, xx, xx) AND issuetype not in subTaskIssueTypes() AND resolutiondate >= -5d OR resolution = unresolved) AND summary ne "mytextToFilterOutOfTheSummary"

Hope it is good to understand - thank very much to all of you :)

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are a number of challenges with getting the information you want:

- JQL doesn't have a way to return the start date of a sprint
- Jira doesn't track if something is closed in a sprint, only it's status and whether or not it is assigned to a sprint
- Jira doesn't have the concept of working days (Monday to Friday)

There are a number of open feature requests around the things you need, but sadly I don't believe they are available yet.

It may be that there are plugins that can help. Other than that, it may be your only option is to use the Jira API to extract issue data and then manipulate it yourself to work out the information you need.